# Inner join among relations

Tags: c#, .net, sql, join

I want to fetch data from three tables: `role`, `permission`, and `right`. I used  inner join.

#### Code

```cs
SqlConnection con = Class3 .GetConnection();
public DataSet showoption1()
{
    string sql1 = "select  right.rightname,role.rolename
                   FROM permission
                   INNER JOIN ON right.rightid = permission.rightid
                   INNER JOIN role ON permission.roleid = role.roleid  ";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql1, con);
    SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adptr.Fill(ds);
    DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];
    return ds;
}
```

#### Database Tables

**Role**

```
Role Id   Role name
  1       admin
  2       employee
```

**Right**

```
rifgtid    rightname
      1    view courses
      2    view assessmenttest
```

**Permission (Associative)**

```
permissionid    rightid     roleid
   1             1           2
   2             1           1
```

Comment: This looks more like a SQL question than a .NET question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [inner join among tables havimg many to many relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030807/inner-join-among-tables-havimg-many-to-many-relationship)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're asking but there is an error on your sql syntax

```
SELECT      right.rightname,
            role.rolename 
FROM        permission 
INNER JOIN  right ON right.rightid = permission.rightid 
INNER JOIN  role ON permission.roleid = role.roleid
```

I replaced `INNER JOIN  ON` by `INNER JOIN  right ON`

As a side note, dispose ADO.NET related objects (SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataAdapter)

Comment: @user1405508: please try again, I had an extra `,` after `role.rolename`

Comment: i have remove it, but problem is same

Comment: @user1405508: run the query on the sql server management and check what it says. I don't see any other problem on the query.

Answer (score 2):

If the table's name is `RIGHT`, then you need to delimit that name, since it's a [reserved word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx), e.g.

```
SELECT      [right].rightname,
            role.rolename 
FROM        permission 
INNER JOIN  [right] ON [right].rightid = permission.rightid 
INNER JOIN  role ON permission.roleid = role.roleid
```

(Stealing @Claudio's query). But I'd actually recommend you revisit the schema and pick a different, non-reserved name for the table.